# Change Tmux key binding?

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to change the tmux keybinding for showing pane numbers in one's tmux configuration file?  I'd like to change it from "q" to "p".  I'm looking at the Tao of Tmux and am not seeing instructions on how to make such a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tmux configuration (~/.tmux.conf) add:

```
unbind p  # to remove current bind
unbind q  # to remove original bind
bind p display-panes # bind new ley to action
```

Comment: `unbind p` isn't strictly necessary; `bind p ...` will replace whatever the old binding was with the new one. (Neither is `unbind q`, for that matter; you can have the same command bound to two keys.)